# how to echo select option value in the php page without AJAX?

Tags: php

I need to find a way to echo the selected option value in the page.

I do not want to use AJAX or javascript if possible.

is this possible using PHP only?

basically when an option is selected, the value of that option should be echo-ed on the page.

My current code is this:

```
<select name="userpages" id="upages">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
            echo '<option value="'.$postResult["page_id"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option>';
        }

    ?>
</select>

<?php echo $postResult["page_id"]; ?>
```

this code will only echo the first selected option value and it won't echo the rest of them if they are selected.

could someone please help me out with this?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it can be done without ajax but not without javascript (unless you have a submit button)

Comment: "*I do not want to use... javascript if possible.*" **Why not**?

Comment: @esqew, because I don't want to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about as javascriptless as you can get

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['userpages'])){
   header ("location:somepage?id=$_POST[userpages]");
   exit;
}

<form method="post">
  <select name="userpages" id="upages">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
            echo '<option value="'.$postResult["page_id"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option>';
        }

    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="load page">
</form>

<?php echo $postResult["page_id"]; ?>
```

you'll have to add an onchange event to the select if you dont want a submit button

Comment: How `<?php echo $postResult["page_id"]; ?>` will work out side of `Foreach loop`. ?

Comment: note i added `exit`, you should do this after a php redirect

Comment: @HarshalMahajan it's not necessary here, but it will be the value from the last iteration of the loop

Comment: @andrew could be possible, but not making sense here.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan its only there because I copied it from the op's post. didn't notice until you pointed it out

Comment: yeah..its not our concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` event is client side activity so we can not get the values of changes using PHP, SO you have to use Jquery for that. 
My solution is without `AJAX` but not without `jquery`

```
        //show the remaining amount 
        $("#upages").live("change", function(event){
            $("#sel_val").html($(this).val());
        });
```

and in your HTML code you should have an HTML element with id `sel_val`.

like `<p id="sel_val"></p>`

Comment: you **have** to use jQuery?

Comment: yes i have give him solution without PHP. other wise the second solution could be `ajax`.

Comment: without PHP? i didn't say without php. i said without javascript or ajax. lol

Comment: without javascript and AJAX :D sorry not possible yet